# How to wait for later started task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

In my code sample main thread doesn't wait when task2 is finished.

```
public async Task Run()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main start");
    await getTask1();
    Console.WriteLine("Main 2");
    var task2 = getTask2();
    await Task.Delay(1);
    Console.WriteLine("Main 3");
    task2.Start();
    await task2;
    Console.WriteLine("Main end");
}

private async Task getTask1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("task1 start");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("task1 end");
}

private Task getTask2()
{
    return new Task(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task2 start");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("task2 end");
    });
}
```

Result of execution this code is

> Main start
>   task1 start
>   task1 end
>   Main 2
>   Main 3
>   task2 start
>   **Main end**
>   task2 end

How can I change code where '**Main end**' will be at the end of list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor overload for `Task` that you are using has the following signature:

```
public Task(Action action)
```

Although you can assign the following expression to a variable of type `Action`:

```
async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task2 start");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("task2 end");
    }
```

this action will point to a synchronous function that will synchronously finish once the `await` in `await Task.Delay(100);` is reached (although the rest of the "action" will continue asynchronously). So, as far as the `Task` object is concerned, the execution of this `Action` is completed once this `await` is reached. This means that the `await` in `await task2;` will asynchronously continue at that point which explains why "Main end" is printed before "task2 end".

So basically, the constructor for `Task` does not support asynchronous actions, just synchronous ones.

To fix this problem, you need to start a task using a method that understands asynchronous actions. An asynchronous action looks like this: `Func<Task>`.

The [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382(v=vs.110).aspx) method supports asynchronous actions because it has the following overload:

```
public static Task Run(Func<Task> function)
```

So to fix your code, change `return new Task(...` to `return Task.Run(...` and then don't call the `Start` method on the returned task since `Task.Run` will create a `Task` that is already started.

If you want to delay the execution of the second "task", then I suggest to make the `getTask2` method return `Func<Task>` (an asynchronous action) instead of `Task` like this:

```
private Func<Task> getTask2()
{
    return async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task2 start");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("task2 end");
    };
}
```

And then run such asynchronous action when you want from the `Run` method like this:

```
public async Task Run()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main start");
    await getTask1();
    Console.WriteLine("Main 2");
    var task2 = getTask2(); //construct asynchronous action
    Console.WriteLine("Main 3");
    await Task.Run(task2); //execute the asynchronous action
    Console.WriteLine("Main end");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `getTask2` you're starting a `Task` that just *starts* another `Task`.  So when you `await` that `Task` it will continue executing as soon as it has finished *starting* the inner task, not when that inner task has *finished*.

In this case there's no reason at all for you to create a new task just to start a new task in the first place; you should just use the approach used in the first method.

Of course, if, for some reason, you *do* need to create a new `Task` just to start a new task then you need to get the inner `Task` out and ensure that the main method only continues executing when that *inner* `Task` has finished.  There is an `Unwrap` method to create a `Task` that is logically equivalent to a `Task` that is the `Result` of another `Task`:

```
private Task getTask2()
{
    Task<Task> task = new Task<Task>(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task2 start");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("task2 end");
    });
    task.Start();
    return task.Unwrap();
}
```

But you don't even need to do that.  `Task.Run` will automatically unwrap the value for you if it is given a lambda that produces a `Task`:

```
private Task getTask2()
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task2 start");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("task2 end");
    });
}
```

And once again, this is all assuming that just *starting* the asynchronous operation needs to be offloaded to another thread, which should be *very* rare.  Usually this means that there's a bug in that asynchronous method in that it shouldn't be doing long running synchronous work before giving you its `Task` in the first place, but on occasion that method will be from an external library that you don't control, so this would be your only option.

Comment: I can't use `Task.Run` because it runs the task2 on any delay in main thread. I added `await Task.Delay(1);` in the sample to show this behavior.

Comment: Like I said in the answer, the correct approach is almost certainly to just do what you're doing in your first solution.  You almost certainly *shouldn't* be using `Task.Run` here because you *don't* need to offload that work to another thread.

Answer (score 0):

`new Task(` does not work with async functions by itself. You are creating a `Task<Task>`, you need to call `Unwrap()` before you await the inner task.

```
private Task<Task> getTask2()
{
    return new Task(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task2 start");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("task2 end");
    });
}

var task2 = getTask2();
Console.WriteLine("Main 3");
task2.Start();
await task2.Unwrap();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an error in your code.  You have not marked the `getTask2` method with the keyword `async` yet you `await` its result.  Even though you are using an `async` delegate within the method you must use the `async` keyword if it is  to be successfully awaited.

Here's an idea as to how you can accomplish your desired result.

```
public async Task Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main start");
        await getTask1();
        await getTask2();
        Console.WriteLine("Main end");
    }

    public async Task AlternateRun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main start");
        List<Task> task_list = new List<Task>();
        task_list.Add(getTask1());
        task_list.Add(getTask2());

        var task_result = Task.WhenAll(task_list);
        task_result.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Main end");
    }

    private async Task getTask1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task1 start");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("task1 end");
    }

    private async Task getTask2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task2 start");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("task2 end");
    }
```

I have also added an AlternateRun method that will demonstrate an alternative style of awaiting multiple tasks.  If you need your tasks to be completed in order then consider using the `ContinueWith` extension method.

Notice that I also removed your `task2.Start()`statement.  This is already implied by the `await` keyword.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A method does *not* need to be marked `async` for it to be awaited.  Any method that returns a `Task` can be awaited.  (Technically, it doesn't even need to be a `Task`, merely an object that has certain properties, of which `Task` qualifies.)  Now yes, the OP's code does have a logical error that prevents it from functioning as he would like it to (obviously it compiles fine, which alone disproves your opening paragraph) but it's entirely unrelated to your claims.

Comment: The OP has the following lines on code 
    task2.Start();
    await task2;
And also indicates that he/she wishes for the routine to end with 'Main End'
This suggest that the OP is awaiting the result of getTask2 which will never be returned in that order.  I do appreciate you pointing out the fact that any task can be awaited nonetheless but I will let the OP judge which answer most likely answered the question.

Comment: Yes, the OP has a bug in his code that results in the operations executing in a different order than what he wants.  That doesn't change the fact that your answer is entirely incorrect in its statements.  The problems with the OPs code are unrelated to what you have claimed they are.  Oh, and while we're at it, your statement that awaiting a task starts it is also completely wrong.  Awaiting a task merely adds a continuation to it that results in the method continuing execution when that task finishes.  It has no bearing on how the task ends up being completed.